# Security token not effective on SonarCloud

Tags: security, sonarcloud

On SonarCloud, I created an organization and a user (from GitHub), plus a project. For the user I created a token. Then I ran the command

```
mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=<project key> -Dsonar.organization=<my org> -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io -Dsonar.login=<token>
```

I come up with the error message

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:sonar (default-cli) on project XXX: You're not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator.
```

In the project settings > Administration > Permissions, the user does have "Execute Analysis" permission.

If I add the "Execute Analysis" permission to Anyone, the command above works (it does not need the `-Dsonar.login` option).

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the "Execute Analysis" permission to the SonarCloud user who generated the token should be enough.

Can you retry with:

```
mvn sonar:sonar 
   "-Dsonar.projectKey=<project key>" \
   "-Dsonar.organization=<my org>" \
   "-Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io" \
   "-Dsonar.login=<token>"
```

In case it doesn't work, can you provide the output of the command?

Comment: Hello @Jean-Alexis.
Yes, this is what I did, to no avail. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I came across the same issue and I had to grant  "Execute Analysis" permission to the the "Anyone" pseudo-group for it to work. This is described [here](https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/analysis/analysis-parameters/#authentication).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that SonarCloud works as expected. I had forgotten that some people in my organization seem to enjoy making their colleagues' life miserable. Sneakily removing items such as `sonar.login` from the requests is one among their tricks.